# How do to keep web pages (like google.com and yahoo.com) from grabing cursor in Safari (form focusing)?

Tags: macos, safari

Certain sites grab the selection from the address bar into their own field when they load. Google and Yahoo Search are two examples as they automatically pull the focus to their search box. Is there a way to turn this off in Safari so the focus stays in address bar?

For context, Firefox supports it via [a preference](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security_Policies#Disable_form_focusing), according to [a Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/28481/can-i-keep-google-from-stealing-my-cursor-in-firefox).

This is [a known feature of HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp).

Answer (score -1):

using safari (or other browsers too) i installed adblock. then i select the search bar that is offendng, right click and tell adblock to block this ad. can be tricky selecting the right amount of the code to block, but a little trial and error will make it work.